Clarification regarding betting game and linearity of expectation
Here is the problem I'm dealing with: You have 3 blue and 3 red cards. These cards are mixed and placed face-down in a deck, ready to be turned over one-by-one. Before each card is turned, you are given the ability to guess whether the card is blue or red. If you guess correctly, you win a dollar. What are your expected earnings from this game?
My Approach
Let $X$ be our random variable representing our winnings. Then, $X$ can be written as $1 + \sum_{i=1}^5 X_{i}$. The 1 at the beginning is because I will always get the last card right.
Then, if I use the linearity of expectation, $E(X) = \frac{5}{2} + 1 = \frac{7}{2}$.
I suspect the reason this is wrong is because $X$ cannot, in fact, be written the way I have described it above. This is because if we get our 3 reds in the beginning, for example, then we will get the last three cards right for sure. Is that the reason why the linearity of expectation doesn't work here?

It's not the linearity of expectation that fails here. Your calculation assumes that for $\ i=1\ $ to $5$, each $\ X_i\ $ is equally likely to be $0$ or $1$. This will be correct if you randomly guess red or blue on your first five guesses.  As you've correctly noticed, however, you can do better than that by adopting a different strategy, and your expected winnings will depend on what strategy you choose.  If, at any stage, you've seen more of one colour than the other, your expected winnings on your next turn will be greater than $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ if you guess the colour that you've so far seen less of.  On the other hand, if you've seen the same number of each colour at a given stage, your expected winnings on your next turn will be $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ no matter which of the two colours you choose.  Your optimal strategy is to guess whichever colour there's more of among the cards left to be turned over.

 \begin{align}&\text{Expectations of}\ X_i\text{s for the optimal strategy:}\\&E(X_1)=\frac{1}{2}\\&E(X_2)=\frac{3}{5}\\&E(X_3)=\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{5}\times\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{5}\\&E(X_4)=\frac{1}{10}\times1+\frac{9}{10}\times\frac{2}{3}=\frac{7}{10}\\&E(X_5)=\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{5}\times1=\frac{7}{10}\\&\sum_{i=1}^5E(X_i)=\frac{31}{10}=3.1\\&\text{Therefore, expected overall winnings are }\$4.1.\end{align}


Yes, absolutely! This makes sense. Thank you!
